# How to use pattern matching in functions with HoldAll atrributes?

Tags: function-construction

For example, I want to define function `f` with `HoldAll` attributes. But its argument must be an Association.

```
ClearAll[f];
ClearAttributes[f, {HoldAll}];
SetAttributes[f, {HoldAll}];
f[a_Association] := a;
```

Now

```
f[<||>]
```

would give

```
<||>
```

which is fine. But

```
assoc = <||>;
f[assoc]
```

just gives

```
f[assoc]
```

because f holds `assoc` and did not check its Head. How to make f also check parameter's head or pattern?

Comment: "because f holds assoc and did not check its Head" is not a correct explanation of what's going on. The head of the expression `assoc` is Symbol, and normally the DownValues for assoc would be used to replace `assoc` with `<||>` before the head is inspected, but you've told the evaluation engine to not do that replacement. You will need to evaluate `assoc` at some point if you want to match against the head `Association`. This could happen as part of the implementation of `f`.

Comment: But stepping back, why do you want `f` to have the `HoldAll` attribute if you actually need your arguments to evaluate?

Comment: `SetAttributes[f, {HoldAll}]; f[a_?(Head[#] === Association &)] := a;`

Comment: Have you read this Chinese tutorial?: http://note.youdao.com/noteshare?id=a9c14381c11b44ad47980c44c200d529

Comment: @lericr Thank you so much for explanation. Well, because I want to modify parameter inside function `f`. So I use `HoldAll`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you so much. This works great!

Comment: @xzczd Thank you for sharing your article, learned a lot.  But please forgive my stupidity, I do not see how to solve my problem after reading it : )

Comment: Actually I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve. `Association` already owns the attribute `HoldAllComplete`, why do you need another `HoldAll`? Have you overloaded `f` with something like `f[a_Plus] := Length@Unevaluated@a`? Anyway, here's a solution similar to @BobHanlon's: `f[a_ /; MatchQ[a, _Association]] := a;` The idea is simple: break the `HoldAll` in some way.

Comment: "because I want to modify parameter inside function f"... So, do you want to modify the symbol `assoc` or do you want to modify the expression `<||>` (or any other association that `assoc` might map to)? If you want to modify the association expression, then you'll need to let `assoc` evaluate at some point. It seems like you're saying "I want function f to manipulate a symbol, but only if that symbol's OwnValues includes an Association." Like, maybe you have a table of symbol names and you want `f` to return `assoc1` if `assoc`'s OwnValues satisfies some criteria. Is that what you're doing?

Comment: @xzczd Thank you for another solution : )

Comment: @lericr Thank you so much for comment. Because in my code. `assoc` is a global variable that is used in many places. I want functions to modify `assoc` directly instead of assign `assoc` after evaluating functions. Set `HoldAll` attribute is the only way I know to modify parameter inside function.